# Samsung Galaxy devices issue: "Server error occurred. Restart Camera"

Tags: camera, samsung-galaxy-s-6

When using the stock camera app on a Samsung Galaxy S6 phone, I sometimes get the error **"Server error occurred. Restart Camera."**

It's then necessary to close the camera app and restart it. It's a hassle that often results in missing photographic shots.  Plus, the last photo taken is not saved.

I have tried clearing the data and cache for the camera app. I have also updated the stock ROM to the latest Nougat version available.  I have performed a factory reset.  Finally, I have sent in the phone ***THREE TIMES*** to Samsung for repairs.  None of these actions has resulted in a solution.

Questions:

- What is causing this?
- What server is the error referring to?
- What is the solution to prevent this error?

Comment: Try clearing cache/data for the Camera app and the Gallery app.

Comment: @RMarkwald Thanks.  Tried it, but server error still occurs. :(