# Does an Android Factory Reset also clear the cache partition?

Tags: factory-reset, camera, partitions, samsung-galaxy-s-6, cache

In researching a possible answer to [this question about "Server error occurred. Restart Camera." while taking photos on the Samsung Galaxy S6](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/179692/samsung-galaxy-devices-issue-server-error-occurred-restart-camera), I read [this article](https://thedroidguy.com/2015/10/samsung-galaxy-note-4-server-error-occurred-restart-camera-error-more-camera-related-issues-1050909#8220server-error-occurred-restart-camera8221-error).

The article talks about wiping the cache partition via Android System Recovery and performing a Factory Reset.

Question: Does an Android Factory Reset also clear the cache partition?  Or does it only clear the data partition?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a factory reset clear's the cache, dalvik cache, along with the user data.

```
<string name="factory_reset1">Wipes Data, Cache, and Dalvik</string>
```

The information on factory reset is hidden in the [Source](https://github.com/omnirom/android_bootable_recovery/blob/baeabc5b436228e0d3bf6c3a1b656a78caaa0fae/gui/theme/common/languages/en.xml) code.